# Capturing Webpages Using Nokogiri -- Need to semi-persistent data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I've got a module that does webscraping.  I use this method a number of times, since it captures all the data on the webpage.

```
def page_as_xml(uri)
  @page_as_xml ||= Nokogiri::HTML(open(uri))
end
```

Since I'll use the above method a handful of times for each page, it makes sense to keep it in an instance variable.  However, how do I "empty out" the instance variable after I'm done?

All the webcsraping ends up in a hash (see below).  If I don't "empty out" the instance variable, then the same page_as_xml data will get used for each page.

```
    :page1 =>
      {
        :url => @page1,
        :title => download_title(@page1),
        :meta_tags => download_robots_tags(@page1) 
      },
    :page2 =>
      {
        :url => @page2,
        :title => download_title(@page2),
        :meta_tags => download_robots_tags(@page2) 
      },
    :page3 =>
      {
        :url => @page3,
        :title => download_title(@page3),
        :meta_tags => download_robots_tags(@page3) 
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about make it a hash:

```
@pages_as_xml[uri] ||= Nokogiri::HTML(open(uri))
```

Now you don't have to worry about emptying it (unless memory is an issue).
I don't really understand why you need to call it more than once though. Also why do you call it page_as_xml if it is html?

Comment: I like the hash strategy.  I call it more than once since I carve up different parts in different methods (e.g. the title method pares down the xml data to just grab a the title.).  If that's a bad idea, let me know.  Also, I call the method page_as_xml because nokogiri returns html documents as xml.

Comment: In the revised method you give, I'm confused about how to use that code.  So if I have a method that relies on having the @pages_as_xml[uri] code, say the method that grabs the title, how would I use it?  I have this a try, but no success                   `def download_title(page)
    xml = pages_as_xml(page)
    xml.at_css('title').text
end`

Comment: There's lots of confusion here, Nokogiri::HTML returns HTMLDocument while Nokogiri::XML returns XMLDocument. I recommend you rename your variables and then post a new question with more code.